# Important examples of measures which are not $\sigma$-finite

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, big-list

I think a measure which is not $\sigma$-finite is pain in the ass.
I wish I could *safely* assume all the measures are $\sigma$-finite.
I wonder if my wish is reasonable.
Here's my question:
what are important examples of measures which are not $\sigma$-finite?
Of course, "important" is a subjective word. So this is a soft question.
This is also a big-list question.

Comment: Most people would avoid measures that are not $\sigma$-finite as many theorems fail miserably. A former advisor of mine said that he thinks a version of Fubini-Tonelli holds in non-$\sigma$-finite spaces (and seemingly had a proof) but he was not entirely convinced by it. Non-$\sigma$-finite measures are very hard to conceive (outside of a few examples) since nearly everything we deal with across swaths of mathematics is $\sigma$-finite. I suggest turning this into a Community Wiki post because it could prove to be very helpful and big list questions usually are Community Wiki.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I've read several times that Fubini theorems remain valid for s-finite measures, measures that are countable sums of finite measures.

Answer (score 18):

Consider ${\Bbb R}^2$ with a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ generated by smooth curves of finite length.  Construct a measure $\mu$ so that $\mu(\gamma) = $length of $\gamma$ if $\gamma$ is a curve.  This is a measure which is not $\sigma$-finite.  The importance of this example is that the map $\mu:\gamma\mapsto\int_{\gamma}d\ell$ is a natural consideration as a measure for an interesting kind of subset (curves) in ${\Bbb R}^2$.  In general, on any $n$-dimension manifold, the measure $A\mapsto \int_{A}\omega$ is not $\sigma$-finite if $\omega$ is a differential form or a pseudo differential form of degree $k<n$.

Answer (score 9):

Counting measure on an uncountable set is not $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: I know.
Could you explain why you think it is important?

Comment: I guess one reason that OP might have (and I agree with), is that the Counting measure is the most natural measure on a set one can think of (at the very least, one of the most natural measures). It is not very important, but it comes naturally.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the most important class of non-$\sigma$-finite measures is provided by the Hausdorff measures.
$\mathcal{H}_{\alpha}$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ where $d > \alpha$ is not $\sigma$-finite. (Because any subset of finite $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha} $ measure is of null Lebesgue measure)

Answer (score 6):

A non trivial measure taking only the values $0$ and $\infty$ is non $\sigma$-finite .

Comment: Could you explain why you think it is important?

Comment: it is useful to keep in mind if you are looking for easy counterexamples, which is all I ever did with this measure :D